# How to click a HTML element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, click

I need to use javascript in order to click an element from element collection. As seen the code has C# but also as seen I need to use a javascript command as I do.

I am looking for this javascript code.

This element doesn't have an ID or name. Otherwise, I could have used the ID but that doesn't work in this case. How would it be possible to use the iterating elements in order to click with javascript"?

**The problems are:**
1. First I need to click this input/textbox to make it possible to edit.
2. Now when the input is editable. I need to put a number value to the textbox.

```js
            foreach (Gecko.GeckoHtmlElement elements in wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
            {
                if (elements != null)
                {
                    if (elements.OuterHtml.Contains("thisstring"))
                    {
                        //This element doesn't have an ID or name. "how to use elements in order to click with javascript"?

                        //1. First I need to click this input/textbox to make it possilbe to edit
                        //2. Now when the input is editable. I need to put a value to the textbox.
                        webbrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(document.getElementById('someID').click())");
                    }
                }
            }
```

The HTML surrounding the element I want to click is below. You can see the input there:

```js
  <td class="date-cell" cm-inventory-grid-copy-action-focus data-header-date-index="0" data-cm-inventory-grid-copy-action-focus-type='availability' ng-class="{ 'zero': roomTypeDatesByRoomTypeId[roomType.id][headerDates[0].fullDate].availability <= 0, weekend: headerDates[0].weekend, 'dirty': roomTypeDatesByRoomTypeId[roomType.id][headerDates[0].fullDate].availabilityChanged, 'copy-focused': roomTypeDatesByRoomTypeId[roomType.id][headerDates[0].fullDate].copyFocused && roomTypeDatesByRoomTypeId[roomType.id][headerDates[0].fullDate].copyFocusType == 'availability' }" ng-form="cellForm">
    
<input name="rtd-availability" type="number" onclick="this.select()" ng-model="roomTypeDatesByRoomTypeId[roomType.id][headerDates[0].fullDate].availability" ng-change="handleRoomTypeDateChange(roomTypeDatesByRoomTypeId[roomType.id][headerDates[0].fullDate])" pattern="\d+" ng-disabled="::!allowAvailabilityEdit" required sm-no-scroll cm-inventory-grid-date-cell-validator/>
  </td>
```

Comment: Can you post the html surrounding the element that you want to click?

Comment: @Wendelin I added the html surrounding the element to my original post. The input has onclick="this.select()" that detects that one need to click it first before it is possible to edit.

Answer (score 0):

To get html element in javascript you can use "document.querySelector('input')" or if there are many input elements you can use "document.querySelectorAll('input')".

querySelector returns HTML node element and querySelectorAll returns array of elements.

Comment: I am not sure if that works in my case? I have this iterating "elements" html object that has no id or name that I need to pass in to the javascript function in some way?

Comment: @Andreas just use
 
webbrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].click())");

it will select first input element of that iterator.

Comment: But doesn't the ('input')[0] just click the first input element in the collection of all inputs?

Answer (score 0):

By using `document.qerySelector` you can identify the correct input quite easily since you can use attributes and the html structure as criteria.

```
//select an input that is a child of a td with class date-cell who's name is rtd-availability
let input = document.querySelector('td.date-cell > input[name=rtd-availability]')
//no need to call .click(), you can use .select() directly
input.select();
input.value = 42;
```

```
javascript:(() => {let in = document.querySelector('td.date-cell > input[name=rtd-availability]'; in.select(); in.value = 42;})();
```

Comment: Thank you. There is a problem though. The problem is that I have about 36 inputs where exactly this would be true: "'td.date-cell > input[name=rtd-availability]'". They have the same "date-cell" class and the same name "rtd-availability". So I can't separate on which to click/set the value. This is why I used a foreach iteration in the first post. I tried to execute this and nothing happened. I am not sure if code finds 36 of the same? webbrowser.Navigate("javascript:(() => {let in = document.querySelector('td.date-cell > input[name=rtd-availability]'; in.select(); in.value = 42;})();");

Comment: This codes puts a rectangle around the input but not actually clicks it so it almost works: webbrowser.Navigate("javascript:void(document.querySelectorAll('input')[" + 5 + "].click())"); It seems that the code actually not activates the: onclick="this.select()" ?

Comment: hmm, as far as I know .click() should activate onclick, but you can also call `.onclick()` directly. Since there are multiple that match this query you can use (:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). E.g.: `table > tr:nth-child(25) > td.date-cell > input[name=rtd-availability]`

Comment: Thank you. I can feel that the solution lies here but I am little confused what the code means. Does it mean the FIRST table in the html code since it is named table only? and does it mean, the 25th tr in THAT FIRST table? It seems that the table I am after is the second table in the HTML code. No Html elements uses any ID.

Comment: This is interesting as a test though. This line of code should work as you mention because it should find the first occurence of this and set the value to 42 but nothing happens?  wb1.Navigate("javascript:void(() => {let in = document.querySelector('td.date-cell > input[name=rtd-availability]'); in.select(); in.value = 42;})();");

Comment: Every 25th row of every table. You can of course also refine the query as much as you want, in the worst case you could start from the `body` element and work your way down from there. If nothing happens I'ld suggest running the JS code in the browser on your target website and debugging it with your browsers debugger. A `debugger;` statement will come in handy.